# How do I use reflection to read properties with the same generic type but different generic arguments?

Tags: c#, reflection

Well, I always can hardcode checking properties in order to solve my case but I want to do it using reflection.

My generic type:

```
public class AnalyzedParameter<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public bool Valid { get; set; }
}
```

My class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public AnalyzedParameter<int> A { get; set; }

    public AnalyzedParameter<string> B { get; set; }
}
```

I need to check each property that has type `AnalyzedParameter` by checking `Valid` property inside.

So my method has to be like this:

```
public bool IsValid()
    {
        var props = GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(AnalyzedParameter<>));
        var valid = props.All(p => ((AnalyzedParameter<object>) p.GetValue(this)).Valid);

        return valid;
    }
```

But it does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part answers your question directly - how to make what you're doing work. The second hopefully changes the problem and makes it easier.

I separated out the part that checks all of these `Valid` properties into a separate class to make it easier for me to work with. (If this was only for `Foo` then you wouldn't need reflection. You already know what properties `Foo` has.

```cs
public static class Validations
{
    // x is a Foo or any other object that 
    // has properties of type AnalyzedProperty<T>
    public static bool IsValid(object x) 
    {
        var analyzedParameterProperties = x.GetType()
            .GetProperties().Where(prop =>
                prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(AnalyzedParameter<>));

        var isValid = analyzedParameterProperties.All(analyzedParameterProperty => 
            GetIsValidValue(x, analyzedParameterProperty));
        return isValid;
    }

    private static bool GetIsValidValue(object x, PropertyInfo analyzedParameterProperty)
    {
        var analyzedParameter = analyzedParameterProperty.GetValue(x);
        if (analyzedParameter == null) return false; // or true?
        var analyzedParameterIsValidProperty = analyzedParameter.GetType()
            .GetProperty("Valid", typeof(bool));
        return (bool)analyzedParameterIsValidProperty.GetValue(analyzedParameter);
    }
}
```

The `IsValid` method takes an object (like an instance of `Foo`) and retrieves all of the properties where the type matches the open generic type `AnalyzedParameter<>`.

The messy part is that you can't use that open generic type to read the `Valid` property on each `AnalyzedParameter` object.

So the second method - `GetIsValidValue`

- Gets the value of the property - an `AnalyzedParameter` object
- Finds a `Valid` property that returns `bool`
- Reads that property and returns its value.

---

This would be much easier if `AnalyzedProperty<T>` implemented some interface that had the `Valid` property. In that case you could just cast each property value as that interface and read the property that way instead of using reflection to find the `Valid` property.

```cs
public class AnalyzedParameter<T> : IHasValidation
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public bool Valid { get; set; }
}

public interface IHasValidation
{
    public bool Valid { get; set; }
}
```

Now the rest of the code can be a little simpler:

```cs
public static bool IsValid(object x)
{
    var analyzedParameterProperties = x.GetType()
        .GetProperties().Where(prop =>
            typeof(IHasValidation).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType));

    var analyzedParameterValues = analyzedParameterProperties.Select(property =>
        property.GetValue(x)).Cast<IHasValidation>();

    // This assumes that if the property is null, it's not valid.
    // You could instead check for value is null or .Valid == true.
    var isValid = analyzedParameterValues.All(value => value?.Valid == true);
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Yep! Only when I have finished my work for today and went out of my home I got to the idea about interface. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because the `PropertyType` of your instance variables is not `AnalyzedParameter<>` but instead `AnalyzedParameter<int>` or `AnalyzedParameter<string>`.

You will likely need to enumerate the types you wish to check for, and construct concrete types from them. For example, in some test code I put together:

```
public class AnalyzedParameter<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public bool Valid { get; set; } = false;
}

public class Foo
{
    public AnalyzedParameter<int> A { get; set; }
    public AnalyzedParameter<string> B { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        var thisType = GetType();
        Log.Verbose($"Type: {thisType}");
        var thisProperties = thisType.GetProperties();
        Log.Verbose($"Properties: {thisProperties}");

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in thisProperties)
        {
            Log.Verbose($"type:{pi.PropertyType}, name:{pi.Name}");
            if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(AnalyzedParameter<>)) Log.Verbose("This property is an AnalyzedParameter<>");
            if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(AnalyzedParameter<int>)) Log.Verbose("This property is an AnalyzedParameter<int>");
            if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(AnalyzedParameter<string>)) Log.Verbose("This property is an AnalyzedParameter<string>");
        }
    }
}
```

```
[10:25:50 VRB] Type: FooTest.Foo
[10:25:50 VRB] Properties: System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[]
[10:25:50 VRB] type:FooTest.AnalyzedParameter`1[System.Int32], name:A
[10:25:50 VRB] This property is an AnalyzedParameter<int>
[10:25:50 VRB] type:FooTest.AnalyzedParameter`1[System.String], name:B
[10:25:50 VRB] This property is an AnalyzedParameter<string>
```